# Adding a hierarchical Gantt-Chart in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, gantt-chart, oracle-jet, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm trying to add a Gantt-Chart (Oracle JET) with hierarchical data to my Oracle Apex (19.1) Application just like the example in the Cookbook ([Hierarchical Tasks](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=hierarchicalTasks)) by using the built-in implementation in Apex.

In this example, a JSON-file containing the tasks, which can have children-elements called `subTasks` gets parsed and rendered. However, I'm getting my data from a local database.

Is this feature possible in the Apex-version of oracleJET? Or do I have to implement the Gantt-chart from OracleJET as if it was a 3rd-party-solution?

Because I am able to create a normal Gantt-chart without a hierarchy, however, I haven't quite figured out, how to implement one with a hierarchy.

According to the documentation of `ArrayTreeDataProvider`, the default-keyword for child-elements to be located in is 'children'. But it doesn't matter how I format my data (selecting it from the database with `json_object()` and `json_arrayagg()` ), it only renders the 'parent' elements.

Does anyone have already implemented this/a similar functionality into an Apex Application and can help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When I have had trouble defining a JET chart within APEX, I have always found it helpful to install the **Sample Charts** app from the **App Gallery**. Oracle does provide some sample Gantt charts with and without a hierarchy on Page 3 (in my instance of APEX 19.2) of the sample application.

Without knowing how your data is structured, we cannot provide an exact solution to your issue, but if you review the setups in the sample application, it should help you out.